# In SCons, how do you escape variable substitution?

Tags: scons

I'm trying to do variable substitution in SCons, followed immediately by characters that can be part of a variable name. If `VARIABLE='first'` I want `"$VARIABLE.name"`to expand to `first.name` instead of raising an error. `$(VARIABLE).name` and `${VARIABLE}.name` didn't seem to work. Am I missing something very obvious?

Comment: Please add a simple MWE to your question, together with the full verbatim error output...then I might be able to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

It's curly braces. Notably it is also possible to use attribute access in variable substitution.

`SConstruct`:

```
class Bag:
    def __init__(self, d):
        self.__dict__ = d

env = Environment(FOO='foo', BAR=Bag({'baz':'quux'}))

env.Command('dummy1', None, 'echo ${FOO}.bar')
env.Command('dummy2', None, "echo $BAR.baz")
```

Outputs

```
scons: Building targets ...
echo foo.bar
foo.bar
echo quux
quux
scons: done building targets.
```

Comment: Not sure what was causing the problem with {} before. Probably just a typo.